# Unable to open a specific site in browser on windows 7

Tags: windows-7, networking, google-chrome, browser

I am trying to open 'https://chrome.google.com' on any browser on my windows 7 machine but for the life of me cannot seem to reach it (its giving a connection timeout error).

I've tried all browsers including FF, Chrome and IE. I can ping the url but just cannot open it in any damned browser. Other devices and systems connected to the same LAN/Wifi network can access the url effortlessly. I tried turning off the firewall and antivirus but to no avail. I even tried the wget command on both the url and its ip, with both failing.

Comment: havent u checked hosts file?whats the result while u were pinging the site?

Comment: Have you tried changing the dns servers on this pc?